# TeXForm errors "TeXForm ofTemplateSlotSequence[1, ] is not supported" and "TeXForm of 0.78492 +1.30714 I is not supported" in 12

Tags: latex, version-12

Reported to WRI. **CASE:4250134**

---

**Update:**
Thanks for the smaller example by Chip Hurst in comment, it seems it comes down to this simpler example

```
 TeXForm[Root[1 + 2 # + #^5 &, 1]]
```

Which gives in **V 12** the following

```
 \text{NumericalApproximation}\left[\text{Root},,\text{Root}
    \left[\text{$\#$1}^5+2\text{$\#$1}+1\&,1\right],\right]
```

With messages in console

```
 TeXForm::unspt: TeXForm of TemplateSlotSequence[1,] is not supported.
 TeXForm::unspt: TeXForm of -0.486389 is not supported.
```

Which compiles to in Latex as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While in Version **11.3**, same input gives

```
 \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^5+2 \text{$\#$1}+1\&,1\right]
```

With no warning messages. which compiles to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it seems Latex output in 11.3 would have been better to keep as is.

---

**Original question**

I am seeing some [TeXForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) errors or new messages in the console in V12 which do not show in V 11.3.

What do these errors mean when calling `TeXForm` on a result returned from `DSolve` in version 12? No such errors come out in 11.3

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[y,x];
ode = -2 x^3 + Log[x] - y[x] + 2 x y'[x] + x^2 y''[x] + x^3 y'''[x] == 0;
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x];
TeXForm[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this a bug? Or just warning message? Is there a way around it? The full Latex expression is too long to show.

btw, I am able to compile the latex generated in Tex Live. So I am not sure what these messages mean. The first part of the output compiles to

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The rest goes over the edge of page since it is too long.

Comment: Seems that `TeXForm` isn't playing nicely with `Root` objects. For example try `TeXForm[Root[1 + 2# + #^5&, 1]]`.

Comment: What do you want the TeXForm of a Root object to be?

Comment: @CarlWoll may be if it was kept as it worked in version 11.3 would be OK.

Comment: `Root` objects are new in 12, but it looks like they were not implemented in `TeXForm`. Have you reported this to support?

Comment: @user6014 `Root objects are new in 12` But Root was introduced in version 3.0? That is what it says at bottom of https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html and yes I just reported it.

Comment: Root objects are not new, nor have they changed, as a language feature, in V12.  All that has changed is how they are displayed.  So the information on the reference page is quite correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you never want to try to create TeX of the new numerical approximations output, you could do:

```
Unprotect[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX];
Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[expr_, o___?OptionQ] /; !TrueQ@$TeX := Block[
    {$TeX=True, BoxForm`UseApproximations=False},
    Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[expr,o]
]
Protect[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX];
```

Then:

```
Root[#^3 + # + 1&, 2] //TeXForm
```

> $\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,2\right]$

If desired, a more targeted version that only affects [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) object is also possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a better fix, which is essentially the one I made to our nightly development version:

```
Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX;
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`StripIdentityBoxes[System`Convert`CommonDump`boxes_]:=
   System`Convert`CommonDump`boxes  //. {
      RowBox[{System`Convert`CommonDump`x_}]:>System`Convert`CommonDump`x,
      InterpretationBox[TemplateBox[_,"NumericalApproximation",___],System`Convert`CommonDump`x_,___] :> 
          Block[{BoxForm`UseApproximations=False},MakeBoxes[System`Convert`CommonDump`x,TraditionalForm]],
      (AdjustmentBox|InterpretationBox|TagBox|DynamicBox|TooltipBox)[System`Convert`CommonDump`x_,___]:>System`Convert`CommonDump`x
   }
```

This version will work not just with `TeXForm` but also with $\TeX$-`Export` and the various other ways $\TeX$ can be generated.

Comment: TeXForm is really overdue for a big update. I hope you are considering it for 12.1.